# VS Code editor intellisense doesn't work with UnityEngine.UIElements namespace

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I can't get any types under UIElements to be picked up by Omnisharp when using VS Code or Vim. I've tried with a minimal project (clean 3d template) with Unity version 2020.3.20f1, Visual Studio Code Editor (Unity package) version 1.2.4, UI Toolkit version 1.0.0-preview.18. I've followed the guide [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ui-toolkit-migration-guide.1138621/) to get the correct compilation order of packages.

Build still works fine, but the editor's intellisense throws squiggles under all UIElements types (e.g. VisualElement, UIDocument).

Answer (score 1):

Change the external script editor (Preferences > External Tools) from Visual Studio Code to Visual Studio Community 2019, then regenerate project files. This seems to work around whatever the issue with Unity is.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to Visual Studio Code Editor v1.2.3. I have the same issue with .4